# Webpack for reactjs with axios working in production but not working in development mode

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I build a crud a application with react and redux, my backend is django.

When i run `npm run build` and run django server, i see my crud application working great! no single issue with this..

But when i run `npm start` it open new link in browser as usual and everything work nice except http request with `axios` it throws me following error:

[image]

but in production mode, it is work..

this is my `webpack.common.js` file

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin  = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './client/index.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/*']) for < v2 versions of CleanWebpackPlugin
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./client/index.html",

    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader"
            }
          }
      ]
  }
};
```

and this is my `webpack.dev.js` file

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
});
```

and this is my `webpapck.prod.js` file

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map'
});
```

and this is my `package.js` file

```
{
  "name": "react-redux-django-crud",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "client/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.prod.js --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "csv-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^4.39.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  }
}
```

I hope you got my issue....

where you go an example http request with `axios`

and this is my table.js file:

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const axios = require('axios');

class Table extends React.Component {
    onEdit = (item) => {  //Use arrow function to bind `this`
        this.props.selectedData(item);
    }

    onDelete = (id) => {
        const data = {
            id,
        }
        axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/employee/' + data.id + '/')
         .then((response) => { //Use arrow function to auto bind `this`
           // handle success
           this.props.dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_POST', data })
         });


    }


    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/employee/')
         .then((response) => { //Use arrow function to auto bind `this`
           // handle success
           this.props.dispatch({ type: 'GET', response })   //considering response.data is the correct array 
         });
     }
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Age</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.employees.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.age}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                onClick={() => this.onEdit(item)}>EDIT
                            </button>
                            <button
                                onClick={ () => this.onDelete(item.id) }>DELETE
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ employees: state.employees });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Table);
```

My API is open, dont have authentication and condition.

this react and django app working fine in production, only problem with development mode. can anyone help me to fix this issue? why it is not working?

Thanks

Comment: You need to configure Django for cors support. The configuration depends on your setup but check out https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers - I've used that package before to set things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add cors setting in your settings.py. This will add Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* to your requests.

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Add to your installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'corsheaders'
)
```

Add middleware.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
)
```

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```